# Sequelize insert into join table many-to-many

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I set up two models in sequelize that have a many-to-many relationship. Sequelize created the join table correctly, but I'm not able to insert into it. I've been poring over this section of the docs: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#creating-with-associations but I can't get anything to work based on their examples. They don't have a many-to-many example, unfortunately.

## Models Relationships :

```
db.user.hasMany(db.post, {through: "likes"});
db.post.belongsTo(db.user, {through: "likes"});
```

```js
Post.findById(postId).then( (post) => {
        try{
            Post.setLikes({userId: 1, postId: 1});
        }catch(e){
            console.error(e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For many to many relationship you must use `belongsToMany` and not `hasMany`

in your case :

```
db.user.belongsToMany(db.post, {through: "likes"});
db.post.belongsToMany(db.user, {through: "likes"});
```

and you can use 3 methodes for manage this relationship `add`, `remove` and `set`

`add` and `remove` add or remove id(s) pass in parameter and `set` replace all ids in relationship by id(s) pass in parameter (set is a remove all + add id pass in parameter)

for exemple:

```
const postId = 1

Post.findById(postId).then( async(post) => {
        try{
            await Post.addLikes([1,2,3]); // 3 relationship are in db postId: 1 with userId: 1,2,3 
            await Post.removeLikes(1); // 2 relationship are in db postId: 1 with userId: 2,3  
            await Post.setLikes(1); // unique relationship is in db postId: 1 with userId:1
        }catch(e){
            console.error(e);
        }
    });
```

you can have more information here https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/has-many.js~HasMany.html#instance-method-add